# Kernel scatterlists contiguous in virtual address?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, virtual-memory

I'd like to ask/verify whether an array of `struct scatterlist` that were mapped with `blk_rq_map_sg` are all contiguous at least in virtual address domain.  Well we all know that scatterlists are primarily for DMA, where each scatter-gather (sg) array element describes a chunk of memory and those chunks are discontiguous in their physical addresses.

I'm writing a block device driver.  Suppose I receive struct requests from my request_queue, and I want to do something with the I/O data that my request is holding, like `memcpy`ing them to somewhere.  That operation will need a virtual address and length parameter.  Now all I know is that I can access the request's data via the scatterlist mapped through the helper function `blk_map_rq_sg()`.  Is my assumption correct, that those sg elements are contiguous in virtual, and that I can get the data address via `sg_virt()`, and use that address and total length for `memcpy`?  Or they are discontiguous in virtual, and I have to walk through each sg array element and `memcpy` to/from each sg memory chunk (in virtual) which is harder?

Comment: Have you tried examining the result of `blk_rq_map_sg`? If they're not contiguous, then you can't make the assumption that they are. If they *are* contiguous, you still can't assume it'll happen 100% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Functions like [writev](http://linux.die.net/man/2/writev) allow to submit discontiguous requests, and pages in high memory do not have a virtual address to begin with.

To access SG list contents with the CPU, use something like `sg_copy_from_buffer`, which automatically maps the pages temporarily.